# Trigger causing an unexpected Exception while inserting a record in to the Object

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a trigger and a part of the trigger acts as a validation rule and it will fire an validation message whenever a user tries to create a Work order on an Expired entitlement. So now I don't see any error in trigger's Helper class but when I create a work order on an expired entitlement, I am seeing a Different message and I Don't think it is an error as I am not being notified about it by Salesforce.

I encounter the following error:

> Error: Invalid Data. Review all error messages below to correct your data. Apex trigger sm1e.WorkOrderTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: sm1e.WorkOrderTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Work order cannot be updated, since Entitlement of this work order is not active.: []: (sm1e)

What changes do I need to make?

Comment: In the future, please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications.

Comment: Sure. I Doubled checked all the validation rules on this object but no rule is blocking this trigger

Comment: Validations via Apex can also cause this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation rule clearly says that you are trying to create work order under a Entitlement which is inactive. You need to activate the `Entitlement` before creating work orders.

You can remove the end date or extend the end date from today's date to make Entitlement as active.

[image: Entitlement detail]

Comment: yeah. I know that the Entitlement is In-active. That is the Whole point. No user  should be allowed to create a Work order if the Entitlement is In-active. If some one tries to, then the following Validation message has to popup on the top of the page "Work order cannot be updated, since Entitlement of this work order is not active" this is the custom text i had on the error Condition ( order.addError('Work order cannot be created, since Entitlement of this work order is not active.'); ). My concern is why am i seeing a long error message. i want to see only my validation message

Comment: because it is getting generated from trigger. The validation message is getting wrapped into the exception message.

Comment: How Can I modify it?

Comment: you can write your own custom message and try to consume that error and show the error. But errors those are getting generated from trigger, it doesn't allow to show only the actually error message. It will show like that. If you use visualforce page then that could be easily achievable by <apex:pagemessages/>

Comment: One last question: we have 6 record types on this object. all record types uses this trigger. so do i need create those many VF pages because fields on each record type is almost different from the other

Comment: no, one page will serve your purpose, always open same page and pass recordtypeId as parameter to URL